# AP Computer Science Logical Operators

Tags: java

Which of the following will evaluate to true only if boolean expressions `A`, `B`, and `C` are all `false`?

> *Answer:* `!(A || B || C)`
>   *My answer:* `!(A && B && C)`

Why is my answer incorrect? If `A`, `B` and `C` are all `false` and the `!` is distributed, it will make all of them `true`, thus returning `true`.

---

Given that `a`, `b` and `c` are integers, consider the boolean expression

```
(a < b) || !((c == a * b) && (c < a))
```

Which of the following will guarantee that the expression is `true`?

> *Answer:* `c < a` is `false`

Doesn't the result rely on `(c == a * b)` being `false` also because of the `&&`?

Comment: Did you draw a logic table, applying the not to the entire expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Keyword: **only**. If at least one of `A`,`B` or `C` is `true`, then `!(A || B || C)` will be `false` (since `A || B || C` will be `true` and `! true` is `false`).
2. > Doesn't the result rely on `(c == a * b)` being false also because of the `&&`?

   No: If `c < a` is `false`, then `(c == a * b) && (c < a)` *must* also be `false`, meaning that the expression `! ((c == a * b) && (c < a))` must be `true`, implying that the entire expression must be `true` (because of the `||`, and the fact that we already know right-hand side will be `true`).

Comment: Thanks! Never expected a reading mistake to be the reason that I get a question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because your expression will evaluate to true if any are false. They don't all have to be false for it to evaluate to true, which is what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

critical words "only if",  with your answer,  other combos of A B and C being false and some true will also yield true.   Though it will also yield true if they are all false, however it says *only if*

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the ! in the first one. you're right, normally that would happen. the same thing is in digital electronics. to get the answer, you have to use or, because it will be true unless they are all the same. It's odd, but it works

Answer (score 0):

The negation operator is not distributed the way you think it is -- see [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). The parenthesis is evaluated first.

I would suggest building up a truth table of your expression to verify its correctness.